# What does "fully visible belief network" stand for?

Tags: generative-model

In CS231n, I saw the terminology "fully visible belief network", one category of explicit density generative model such as PixelCNN and NADE.

Although I can understand what this terminology wants to say, but I need more explanations in detail:

1. What exactly does "fully visible" (or "visible") mean?
2. I have searched about deep belief net, and I believe that it is just a model in category of deep neural network but trained in unsupervised way with energy function. Am I right?

Comment: deep belief net has little to do with neural network, if not sharing the concept of "neurons" but they are defined in 2 very different ways, though, i have no idea what they mean with _fully visible belief network_... maybe having no "hidden/latent variables", but it's a pretty loose definition

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand in the context of the lecture. I'm assuming you're referencing this slide in [Lecture 12](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/2021/slides/2021/lecture_12.pdf):
[image: CS231n Lec 12, slide 16: Taxonomy of Generative Modles: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/2021/slides/2021/lecture_12.pdf]

What distinguishes the FVBNs from the other explicit density models are that they have a *tractable density*: that is, that you can exactly calculate the probability of samples of your dataset (or at least, that's the assumption made by the model). **This is what's meant by "fully visible"**.

Take PixelRNN/CNN, for example. Here, you model images autoregressively, where a given pixel only depends on previous pixels. This allows you to decompose the distribution over many pixels using the chain rule. [Look at slide 23 in the lecture for more info.](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/2021/slides/2021/lecture_12.pdf) **The main idea is that this decomposition allows you to calculate the probability of a sample exactly, making it "fully visible".**

The connection to deep belief networks is a bit more iffy in my opinion. The [NADE paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/16-272/16-272.pdf) explains how the NADE forward pass is similar to an approximation of a RBM. I'm unsure if this extends to other models, however.